# How is the theoretical maximum file size on filesystems like XFS calculcated?

Tags: files, filesystems, size, xfs

Documentation for XFS claims its current theoretical maximum file size is 8 exbibytes - 1 byte. However, I am wondering how this calculation was computed? I cannot seem to find discussion of this elsewhere, and I am also curious if there is a way for me to verify this if I have the filesystem mounted?

Comment: If you have a link to the documentation where the max file size is given, that would be welcome.

Comment: [here](https://xfs.org/docs/xfsdocs-xml-dev/XFS_User_Guide/tmp/en-US/html/ch02s04.html)

Comment: Thanks, but I read "9 ExaB", not 8 EiB-1

Comment: oh oops, I must have been thinking of the max file size listed on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XFS)

Answer (score 4):

> I am wondering how this calculation (8 exbibytes - 1 byte) was computed?

The file size is stored in a signed 64 bit integer, which goes from -2^63 to 2^63-1. Since an exbibyte is 2^60 bytes, 2^63-1 corresponds to 8 exbibytes - 1 byte.

> I am also curious if there is a way for me to verify this if I have the filesystem mounted?

Yes, try this:

```
truncate -s 9223372036854775807 test && ls -l test
```

... or this if you don't have `truncate`:

```
dd if=/dev/null of=test bs=1 seek=9223372036854775807 && ls -l test
```

(you guessed it, 9223372036854775807 is 2^63-1)

Answer (score 2):

In general, even if the size isn't explicitly stored, two things must be: where the chunks of data are stored, and how big each chunk can be. You take the maximum value for each, and multiply to get the maximum file size. The specifics depend on each filesystem. In XFS the chunks are called "extents" and the number of extents (`di_nextents` according to [the draft XFS documentation](https://xfs.org/docs/xfsdocs-xml-dev/XFS_Filesystem_Structure//tmp/en-US/html/On-disk_Inode.html#Inode_Core)) is [a signed 32 bit integer](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/dd860052c99b1e088352bdd4fb7aef46f8d2ef47/fs/xfs/libxfs/xfs_types.h#L15). The size of the extents (`di_extsize`) is an [unsigned 32 bit integer](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/dd860052c99b1e088352bdd4fb7aef46f8d2ef47/fs/xfs/libxfs/xfs_types.h#L13). That gives (2^32 - 1)*(2^31 - 1), which is a relatively tiny bit (2^32 + 2^31 - 1 = 3*2*2^30 - 1 ~ 6 GiB) less than 8 EiB.

Depending on the filesystem, the number of chunks itself can be a bit more complex to find out (e.g., each inode might have a list of N data blocks and a list of M other inodes for that file, up to a depth of K, then you get a limit of N*(M^(K+1) - 1)/(M-1) data blocks total).